# How to check which anchor <a> link has been clicked vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, actionfunction

I have this below links in a vf page -

```
    <p style="line-height: 1.5em;list-style-position: initial;margin:0;padding:0;"><a onclick="callAction()" target="_blank" href="https://cs1.salesforce.com/00O80000002zam7" style="text-decoration:none;color:#1468b6; position: relative; left: -30px;">Test1</a></p> 
    <p style="line-height: 1.5em;list-style-position: initial;margin:0;padding:0;"><a target="_blank" href="https://cs1.salesforce.com/00OC0000006LnZ1" style="text-decoration:none;color:#1468b6; position: relative;left: -30px;">Test2</a></p>
<p style="line-height: 1.5em;list-style-position: initial;margin:0;padding:0;"><a target="_blank" href="https://cs1.salesforce.com/00OC0000006LaGZ" style="text-decoration:none;color:#1468b6; position: relative;left: -30px;">Test3</a></p>    
<p style="line-height: 1.5em;list-style-position: initial;margin:0;padding:0;"><a target="_blank" href="https://cs1.salesforce.com/00OC0000004l4vm" style="text-decoration:none;color:#1468b6; position: relative;left: -30px;">Test4</a></p>    
<p style="line-height: 1.5em;list-style-position: initial;margin:0;padding:0;"><a target="_blank" href="https://cs1.salesforce.com/00OC0000004l4vI" style="text-decoration:none;color:#1468b6; position: relative;left: -30px;">Test5</a></p>
```

And onclick i am calling action:function -

```
<script>
function callAction(){
  controllerAction();
}
</script>

  <apex:actionFunction name='controllerAction' action="{!openPage}" reRender='fm'>
    <apex:param name="report1" value="Test1" assignTo="{!report1}"/>
    </apex:actionFunction>
```

What i want is onclick i should be passing some value to function regarding which link i had clicked and assign the value to `report1` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `<a>` tag change the onclick to:

```
onclick="controllerAction('YOURVALUE')"
```

No need for the additional JS function `callAction` as the actionFunction creates a JS function with the actionFunction name